# What's a clean way to toggle between several objects using armatures?

Tags: armature, workflow

Given five objects, what good ways are there to use bone switch(es) to make sure only one of them is visible at one time, without having to manually key "Restrict Render?"

Comment: Can you give a few details as to how this is different from your previous question "Switching visible objects via driver"?

Comment: @RayMairlot, I'm trying to explore alternate solutions to the same problem, e.g. individual switches for each object.